# Regex Select Different Email Formats in HTML

Tags: python, regex, email

I'm new to Regex and currently writing a Scrapy crawler to collect e-mail addresses.

I want to be able to select different formats of e-mails when I crawl. Right now I just find anything with an @ sign - but want to be a little bit smarter.

How do I select e-mails with the following formats?

- info@example.com
- info [at] example [dot] com
- info at example.com info
- info at example dot com

Here is what I currently have:

```
item['mail'] = hxs.select('//body//text()').re(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+')
```

Comment: It's hard to write a correct regex for email addresses.  See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1281433).  Getting even more formats, like you're asking for will be even harder.  Since people usually try formats like your last three to **avoid** scrapers (though it's not particularly effective), you may meet some resistance in this question.

Comment: I know, that's why I need help with it - very new to this field and my research and attempts haven worked so far. That's why I need someone who is experienced at this.

Comment: Regarding the link above - I'm not trying to validate the e-mail. I never said that, I'm just trying to find a pattern that matches those above on the page and collect them.

Comment: Yes, but my point was that it's a very hard task to write a regex that matches all emails, and you're asking for something even more powerful than that.

Comment: Makes sense, read more deeply into it - and it does seem like a complex issue.

Comment: It seems unethical to help you scrape email addresses from people who are trying to keep them private.

Comment: That really depends on how you use it. I'm gathering it for my own purposes in a strategic manner. The reason they do that is so people don't spam them - not for people not to contact them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with, but I really don't know if it  is going to work for you unless you provide more examples.

With the current examples in your question, it works. If you don't care about email addresses that are more complex than that, then this should be fine for you.

```
[\w.-]+ ?(?:@|\[?at]?) ?[\w.-]+(?: ?\[?dot]? ?[\w.-]+)?
```

So what did I do here?
I put in an alternation at the `@` symbol so that it can either accept `[at]` or `at` by using optional spaces and brackets with the lazy quantifier: `?`

```
 ?(?:@|\[?at]?) ?
^              ^
   lazy spaces
```

I did similar towards the end of the expression, but I made the entire non-capturing group optional, since it would mess with the first couple lines in your example emails otherwise.

https://regex101.com/r/aC4kW3/1

Comment: Thanks so much! I was close, I didn't use the ? in the places where you have them. Lesson learned.

Comment: It seems to work in the program you linked but not in practice. It was simply selecting words with at or those with spaces.

Comment: It all depends on your data, your options, what language you are using, etc... I'd need more details

Comment: Well they are basic pages with contact information in them. So for example. http://decorchick.com/advertise/ or http://lifeinsketch.com/advertise/